# How to get at V8 Runtime metrics?

Tags: node.js, v8, metrics

Is there a way to expose V8 runtime metrics so I can point some code I wrote to scrape them periodically?

Comment: It's too basic a question, which begs to wonder - What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried inspector-vm which it appears to be only specific to that application.  I've also looked at d8 but this isn't exactly what I want either.  I just want an endpoint that reports back all of V8's runtime metrics

Answer (score -1):

[RuntimeTools/appmetrics](https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics) is your Google's top search result. Other than that, there are a few ways. But from your question I suspect you haven't even tried to look around before asking.

Comment: The comments section is a bit above.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I gave an answer, not a comment.